# Poset of nonvanishing minors of a matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, posets

This question was posed on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568765/properties-of-poset-of-nonvanishing-minors-of-a-matrix?noredirect=1#comment5301649_2568765) three days ago, but hasn't gotten any answers or suggestions. I hope it's okay to ask it on MO, but if I should wait a little longer, please just let me know.

Say $M$ is a (finite) matrix with entries in your favorite field. Let $P$ be the collection of nonvanishing minors of $M$, ordered by inclusion in the natural way. The height of $P$ is the rank of $M$. What else can one say about $P$? For example, here are some naive questions:

1. What is the width of $P$? (Does it have any natural meaning, like the height of $P$ being the rank of $M$?)
2. Does $P$ have the Sperner property?
3. What posets can be realized in this way? Does it depend on the field? What if we restrict to integer $0$-$1$ matrices?

For instance, $P$ can't be a linear order, except in the pretty trivial case that $M$ has at most one nonzero entry.

All the same questions can be asked for the poset of square submatrices of $M$ with nonzero permanent. The questions were inspired by [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284745/on-a-permanent-related-rank).

Comment: Isn't what you're describing just a (realizable) matroid?

Comment: @SamHopkins I guess if you project the nonvanishing minors onto their column indices (or row indices) then you get the usual independence matroids. I'll think about that. But I don't think my poset is itself a matroid (or if it is, I don't see it). Thanks for your observation, but off the top of my head, I think it still leaves my questions open.

Comment: The way I am used to getting a matroid in this situation is the following. Suppose for simplicity M is a nxn square matrix. Then consider the nx(2n) matrix M’ obtained by putting a nxn identity matrix in front of M. Then (up to sign, which shouldn’t matter here) the *maximal minors* of M’ correspond to *all of the minors* of M, and hence the nonvanishing minors of M correspond to the bases of the column matroid of M’.

Comment: But yes, you care about more here: the order on bases. I’m not sure exactly what this order is (it’s not just e.g. lexicographic order, as far as I can tell).

Comment: Perhaps, you want to check out the concept of linking systems due to A. Scrijver (1974). It is equivalent to matroids.